# Already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to call the InitializeComponent method, although I get the following error:

```
Type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types
```

Code as follows:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

............

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.Browser = new WebBrowser();
      this.panel1 = new Panel();
      this.txtNavigate = new TextBox();
      this.cmdGo = new Button();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, that's obvious, your class already have a InitializeComponent method. To find it, comment out the one you made, go to the constructor, place the cursor inside the identifier InitiailizeComponent and hit F12, that will take you to it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you haven't already, please take a look through the [faq] and the [ask] pages to find information on how to post good questions on this site. In particular, try to give us as much information as we require in order to help you.

Comment: Copy/pasting a .NET 1.1 sample you found requires going slow, one declaration and one method at a time.  Paste it all and you just get a mountain of errors that you can't sort out.  Not mentioning this in your question doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

There's already a method called InitializeComponent defined, check the designer generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **private** key word with **partial**:

```
partial void InitializeComponent()
```

This way you can have as many members with the same name as you want.